# Fonts not applied on style unless hot-reloaded in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using `global` object to store font names (so later I can change all the fonts), but some how they not applied unless I save the component (and trigger hot-reload).
After experiments I found that `global` do not store values in the beginning, so the hot reload have to re-assign values to global variables that closured.

Code:

**App.jsx**

```
...
global.fontRegular = 'Montserrat-Regular';
global.fontSemiBold = 'Montserrat-SemiBold';
global.fontExtraBold = 'Montserrat-ExtraBold';
...
```

**HeaderTitle.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#f1f1f1',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: global.fontExtraBold,
    margin: 10,
  },
});

export default function () {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.text}>SUPPORT.UA</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

### Screen before hot-reload

[image: Screen before hot-reload]

### Screen after hot-reload

[image: Screen after hot-reload]

Answer (score 0):

What I found out, is that using `global` object do not work for enclosured object if not in export body, so original code **WILL NOT WORK**,

but the following one **WILL** (now I wonder how this works):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default React.memo(function ({navigation, ...props}) {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
      fontSize: 24,
      color: '#f1f1f1',
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontFamily: global.fontExtraBold,
      margin: 10,
    },
  });
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MainScreen')}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>SUPPORT.UA</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `const styles` object is declared outside a function block, therefore it is evaluated immediately on app launch (with `global.yourFont` being unassigned yet). However, assignments to `global` are operations, that are done after the entire code has been crawled and unscoped `const`'s have been evaluated. Therefore, moving it inside a component fixes the problem, because the component function will be called way after the initial crawl.